Title in several lines make different spacing with apa7
Why would the linebreaks in the title lead to different spacing? Can someone help fix the space between the 3rd and the 4th line?
This is the minimal example:
\documentclass[doc,12pt,a4paper,floatsintext,natbib]{apa6}

\title{Title:\\
    line 2,\\
    line 3,\\
    line 4}
\twoauthors
    {First Author}{Second Author}
\twoaffiliations
    {Affiliation 1}
    {Affiliation 2}
\authornote{
    \noindent
    Please send correspondence to Author 1: author1@email.com \\
}
\abstract{
    XXXX
}
\keywords{
    XXXX
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\noindent
XXXX

\newpage
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\end{document}

and this is the output:

Here is a surprising fix: just add \\ on the last line as well:
\title{Title:\\
    line 2,\\
    line 3,\\
    line 4 \\
    }


Or, you can manually adjust the spacing with \vspace. This is easier if you use the parskip package. Then you can just add \vspace{\parskip} as below to get the correct spacing:
\documentclass[doc,12pt,a4paper,floatsintext,natbib]{apa6}
\usepackage{parskip}
\title{Title:\\
    line 2,\\
    line 3,\\
    \vspace{\parskip} % Adjust the value as needed
    line 4}
\twoauthors
    {First Author}{Second Author}
\twoaffiliations
    {Affiliation 1}
    {Affiliation 2}
\authornote{
    \noindent
    Please send correspondence to Author 1: author1@email.com \\
}
\abstract{
    XXXX
}
\keywords{
    XXXX
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\noindent XXXX

\newpage
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\end{document}

Or, you can remove the spacing with \vspace{-\parskip} if you prefer (you'll need to add \vspace{-\\} before the last line to get the same spacing on the last line):
\title{Title:\\
    \vspace{-\parskip}
    line 2,\\
    \vspace{-\parskip}
    line 3,\\
    \vspace{-\\}
    line 4
    }


You can play around with the spacing to get what you want.

Unfortunately, only the last solution worked, and it needs a lot of tweaking. I gave up on apaX and went back to the plain old article. Then, everything got sorted.
